# Visual Studio Code C++ Extension slow in displaying errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am new to C++ programming and when I started to code in Visual Studio Code, the error displaying of the extension is very slow and I get the following output:

[image: Error image]

I tried searching the problem on the web, but there weren't any solutions. I have the following extensions installed:

[image: Extensions]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: if it was really fast you would complain VSC is taking 100% CPU while typing

Comment: slow compared to what? Having **no** errors shown would be a bigger problem, a few years ago you did not have instant error messages while typing, only compiling would give you the errors (a lot of them)

Comment: disable all extensions you don't use for that particular workspace

Comment: then use the flutter extension

Comment: I was talking about when I use the flutter extension for developing flutter apps->https://flutter.dev/

Comment: the C++ extension is open source so you can submit a pull request

Comment: In my case I had a slow-down of more than 5 seconds, and I eventually noticed that there was an extension which required reloading. Resolved the problem for me...

Answer (score 4):

In the Visual Studio Code settings you can configure the delay after which code analysis starts.

[image: Screenshot of intelli sense update delay setting]

There is a delay because typically *while writing* such processing would be wasted effort and performance.

If you deem the delay too long, you can reduce it to your preferences.

Answer (score 3):

This is working normally. Code highlighting and squiggles always take some time to load. They can take as little as ~0.5 seconds and as long as 5 seconds in a large project. Intellisense specifically waits for you to stop typing for a little while (about  half a second maybe?) to even begin parsing the input and looking for errors.